# Using dropdown to add/remove search boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a drop down that will have 3 categories in it. I would like to to have so that when the user chooses a category, the correct number of search boxes for that category will appear. I then want the text that is inputted into the search boxes to be saved as a variable in the URL. Here is what I got

http://jsfiddle.net/2yWzc/1/

HTML:

```
<form class="list" action="table.php" method="get">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="name">
                <td>First Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="searchBox" name="q1" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="name">
                <td>Last Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="searchBox" name="q2" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="owner">
                <td>Owner:</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="searchBox" name="q1" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="dlp">
                <td>Text 1:</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="searchBox" name="q1" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="dlp">
                <td>Text 2:</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="searchBox" name="q2" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="dlp">
                <td>Text 3:</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="searchBox" name="q3" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="SEARCH" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <br>

    <select id="options">
        <option value="name">Option 1</option>
        <option value="owner">Option 2</option>
        <option value="dlp">Option 3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#options').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'name') {
        $('.name').show();
        $('.owner').hide();
        $('.dlp').hide();
    } else if ($(this).val() == 'owner') {
        $('.name').hide();
        $('.owner').show();
        $('.dlp').hide();
    } else if ($(this).val() == 'dlp') {
        $('.name').hide();
        $('.owner').hide();
        $('.dlp').show();
    }
});

$(function(){
    $('form').bind('change', function () {
        var url = $(this).val();

        if (url) {
            window.location = url;
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

This shows the correct number of searchboxes, but it doesn't save the text in the search boxes in the variables. It also seems like it isn't a good way to do it (If you know of the proper way, point me in the right direction. This was the only thing I could do that would work). Before this, I had 1 search box per category, so my JS code was this

```
(function($) {
    $(function(){
        $('form').bind('change', function () {
            var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value

            if (url) { // require a URL
                window.location = url; // redirect
            }

            return false;
        });
    });
})(jQuery)​;
```

However, I have no idea how to get it to work for multiple search boxes. I only want variables for the search boxes that are shown to be passed via URL (again, so maybe this isn't the proper way?).

Can anyone help me out? Thanks

Comment: you want the redirect to happen when you click the "search" button?

Comment: Yes. Or when the user hits Enter. I'm trying to get the text that is shown in each search box (as well as the dropdown category) to be passed via URL to another page

Comment: You want to pass the values entered in the input field and the selected option text as query parameter in the URL ?

Comment: @Harry - Sorry! The table is in a form on my site. I'll update the code. Farhan - Yes. As separate variables (E.g. ?q1=something&q2=something&t=name)

Comment: disabling the hidden elements will prevent them from being submitted with the form, see http://jsfiddle.net/2yWzc/3/.  Is this what you're asking?

Comment: Almost. The hidden inputs in your example still get submitted, they just don't have a value (E.g. Yours outputs: q1=dsfssdf&q2=dsfsdf&q1=&q1=&q2=&q3=&t=name). Harry's works as I'd like, but you raised a good point about using the & sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below.

An event handler is bound to the form's `submit` event. Within it, we get a list of all input elements with `type="text"` that are present inside the form and pick up only the fields that are visible using the `filter` method. Then we traverse the list of elements and form the dataString. This dataString is of the format `q=a&q1=b` and will be appended to the URL. `encodeURIComponent` is used to encode the dataString.

```
$(function(){
    var dataString = "";
    var url="sample.htm";
    var count=0;
    $('form').bind('submit', function () {
        $('form input[type="text"]').filter(':visible').each(function(){
            if(count === 0)
                dataString += this.name + "=" + $(this).val();
            else
                dataString += '&' + this.name + "=" + $(this).val();
            count++;
        });
        //console.log(dataString);
        dataString += "&t="+$("#options").val(); //appending the value of the select box
        if (url) {
            window.location = url + "?" + encodeURIComponent(dataString); //added for the URL encode
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

[**Updated Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/2yWzc/9/)

Comment: Constructing urls like this is often more trouble than it's worth.  The first issue that comes to mind is url characters like an Owner field value of "Bernie & Phyl's".  The & will cause problems because you did not urlencode the values in your example

Comment: @maj0rtom: There was one issue where the '&' was getting added even before the first parameter, I have addressed that now. Since we are encoding, I think it has to be decoded first. But I don't have much experience of doing it in PHP. Let me see if I can find any samples.

Comment: This updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/2yWzc/9/) might help you mate. You can then use `rawurldecode($_GET['q'])` to get the values.

Comment: @maj0rtom: I just checked in IE8 and it is working fine. Does the console report any errors?

Comment: Well I'm using IE10, and setting it to compatibility mode. The script doesn't filter out the inputs boxes that are hidden (So it is passing ?q1=something&q2=something&q1=&q1=&q2=&q3=&t=name, for example). I'm assuming it has something to do with the line `$('form input[type="text"]').filter(':visible').each(function(){`. I'll see if I can write a fallback for when all variables are passed

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way to do that, but here is an update to your jsfiddle that will do what you want

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type=submit]').bind('click', function () {
        count = 0;
        url = '';
        $("input[type=text]").each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":visible")){
                count++;
                if(count != 1){
                    url += "&";
                }
                url += "var"+count+"="+$(this).val();
            }
        });
        if(count != 0){
            url += "&";
        }
        url += "count="+count;
        url += "&option="+$("#options").val();
        alert(url);
        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2yWzc/4/